# Updating the remoteView after being used in a custom content notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to create a media player controls notification using a custom remoteView. the problem I got into is that each time I change something in the remote view, I need to cancel the notification and rebuild it from scratch. This method is very bad for performance as it visibly lags. ( i.e changing the pause icon to play icon only, I would need to rebuild the entire notification and reload the album image too )

I tried changing the remoteView and then setting it back again using the `NotificationBuilder.setCustomContentView` but it didn't work, here is the code of changing the play and pause icons :

```
public void PlayPause(){
        this.play=!this.play;
        if (this.play) {
            Bitmap toggleBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), R.drawable.baseline_pause_black_48);
            remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.toggle, changeBitmapColor(toggleBmp,Color.parseColor(iconColor)));

        } else {
            Bitmap toggleBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_black_48);
            remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.toggle, changeBitmapColor(toggleBmp,Color.parseColor(iconColor)));

        }

        nBuilder.setCustomContentView(remoteView);
    }
```

The upper code doesn't work and the icons don't change.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update a notification with new information, without having to cancel the original notification.

If you create your notification with a unique ID, you can then use that ID to update the notification by using the `NotificationManager.notify(id, notification)`.

Where `id` is the unique ID of the notification you want to update and `notification` is a Notification object either created with new content or updated.

This [site](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/notify-user/managing.html) has an example of how to update a notification in Java.